# Variable modification in golang [Mutability]

Tags: go

The below code opens up a .txt file and counts the word frequencies. I am following a book and I got confused:

My question is here:

```
filename := os.Args[1]
frequencyForWord := map[string]int{}
updateFrequencies(filename, frequencyForWord)
fmt.Println(frequencyForWord)
```

I create a variable called `frequencyForWord` and pass it into a function that does not return anything called `func updateFrequencies`

This function modifies the variable and that's why when I do `fmt.Println(frequencyForWord)` it shows me a map that has words as keys and their counts as values.

My question is:

why don't I have to do something like this

```
frequencyForWord = updateFrequencies(filename, frequencyForWord)
fmt.Println(frequencyForWord)
// And then change func updateFrequencies to something to returns a map
```

I thought in order for a function to modify a variable I need to pass in the variable as a reference like this `updateFrequencies(filename, &frequencyForWord)`

Original Code:

```
package main

import(
"fmt"
"path/filepath"
"os"
"log"
"bufio"
"strings"
"unicode"
)

func main() {
  if len(os.Args) == 1 || os.Args[1] == "-h" {
    fmt.Printf("usage: %s <file>\n", filepath.Base(os.Args[0]))
    os.Exit(1)
  }
  filename := os.Args[1]
  frequencyForWord := map[string]int{}
  updateFrequencies(filename, frequencyForWord)
  fmt.Println(frequencyForWord)
}



func updateFrequencies(filename string, frequencyForWord map[string]int) string {
  file, err := os.Open(filename)
  if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Failed to open the file: %s.", filename)
  }
  defer file.Close()
  readAndUpdateFrequencies(bufio.NewScanner(file), frequencyForWord)
}

func readAndUpdateFrequencies(scanner *bufio.Scanner, frequencyForWord map[string]int) {
  for scanner.Scan() {
    for _, word := range SplitOnNonLetter(strings.TrimSpace(scanner.Text())) {
      frequencyForWord[strings.ToLower(word)] += 1
    }
  }

  if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
}

func SplitOnNonLetter(line string) []string {
  nonLetter := func(char rune) bool { return !unicode.IsLetter(char) }
  return strings.FieldsFunc(line, nonLetter)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the map structure doesn't contain the values itself but points to the structures holding the values.

As written in [the documentation](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#maps) :

> Like slices, maps hold references to an underlying data structure. If
>   you pass a map to a function that changes the contents of the map, the
>   changes will be visible in the caller.

That's just like when you pass a pointer to a function : it lets the function change your value.

Here's another example of the same phenomenon :

```
type A struct {
    b *B
}
type B struct {
    c int
} 
func incr(a A) {
    a.b.c++
}
func main() {
    a := A{}
    a.b = new(B)
    fmt.Println(a.b.c) // prints 0
    incr(a)
    fmt.Println(a.b.c) // prints 1
}
```

Comment: ...and the implementation of a map value is a plain old pointer to an opaque run time structure.

Comment: For all practical purposes, you end up doing `call-by-reference` instead of the usual `call-by-value`. You pass the value, but the value is essentially a pointer-based data-structure, the underlying data-structure will be referenced by both variables.

Answer (score 2):

The function is not modifying the *variable*, but the *value* bound to the variable. That's possible because a `map` is a mutable data structure and passing it to a function does not copy the structure. (A `map` is implicitly a *reference* to a hash table and the reference is passed around.)